# paramiko exec_command redirect to a file

Tags: paramiko

I want to capture the screenshot of a remote computer using paramiko. I am using the following code for that

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('10.93.80.63', username='root', password='bohica')
ssh.exec_command("xwd -display :0 -silent -root > myscreen.xwd")
ssh.close()
```

The issue is that the file myscreen.xwd is created but the size is 0. Could you please let me know how I can capture the screenshot.

Comment: Resolved this issue. The issue was that xwd was not executable and was not in the standard path. Resolved this issue by moving xwd to the standard path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this issue. The issue was that xwd was not executable and was not in the standard path. Resolved this issue by moving xwd to the standard path.